# QGIS failing to install

Tags: qgis, installation

I am an absolute beginner with QGIS and try to install the software in order to set my first step, with a tutorial that I have found on Youtube (https://youtu.be/NHolzMgaqwE). I'm working with Windows10.

So far I have tried to install two different versions:
<QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.28.7-1.msi> which is said to be the most stable, and
<QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.30.3-1.msi> which is said to be the latest.

In both cases, I get the installer to ask me to repair the software, no other options are available. So I click "repair" and then the installer crashes, or just freezes. Nothing happens and the software doesn't get installed.

What could I do wrong?

Is there another / better way to install the right software?

Comment: Try to install through the OSGeo4W installer as in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pja_EX0tVZA&ab_channel=HansvanderKwast

Comment: It seems to run, this install. Just after half an hour only 4% has been finished. Is that how it should be?

Comment: The installer needs to download and install a lot of packages when it is run for the first time. 4% in half an hour feels still rather slow, but much depends on the speed of the network.

Comment: What is your Operating System and Specs (RAM/CPU).

Comment: I'm on Windows 10, with

Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570 CPU @ 3.40GHz   3.40 GHz
Geïnstalleerd RAM-geheugen 16,0 GB (15,9 GB beschikbaar)
Type systeem 64-bits besturingssysteem, x64-processor

My internet connection is with glass fiber.